# "Onbeforeunload" intercepts selenium click

Tags: python, selenium, onbeforeunload

[webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2mPd.jpg)
[image]
I try to click a start button on a webpage using selenium:

> WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
> (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="element"]'))).click()

'element' is just to simplify code.

But an exception error appears:

> Message: element click intercepted: Other element would receive the click: <body onbeforeunload="Unload()" onunload="Unload()"...

What i've already tried:

1. driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};") # doesn't work
2. options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking") # doesn't work again
3. driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
4. ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

Unfortunately, i know nothing about the HTML or JavaScript for now, but realize that some kind of overlay covers this button. How to disable it?

UPD: yes, i switched to "Content" iframe to make a click action.

Comment: Share the URL or update question with HTML code.

Comment: The Element is in an `iframe`, tried with all the options but dint work. May be the Website is not allowed to automate.